# C++ recursive function return value

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, binary-search-tree, return-value

As a homework, I am implementing a binary search tree, and was doing the part of searching for a position of some data (to be able to modify/remove it later), here is my piece of code:

```
node*& bst::search(data& x, node*& pos) {
    if (pos->get().num == x.num) {
        return pos;
    }
    if (pos->right != NULL) search(x, pos->right);
    if (pos->left != NULL) search(x, pos->left);
}
```

In the source file I call `search(data_to_find, root)`. In my example I had a tree of integers of this form:

```
1
 2
  3
```

with the root pointing to 1. When I wanted to search for element 3, I was expecting to get the pointer to 3, but every single time this function returns the root itself. Then I thought maybe this had to do with the first instance of foo not returning a value, so I changed `search(x, pos->right)` to `return search(x, pos->right)` and same for left, and this time everything worked OK. This made me confused, I tried to do a few runs with the following dummy function just to understand what would it return

```
int foo(int x = 0) {
    if (x == 1) {
        return x;
    }
    x++;
    foo(x);
}
```

Although I haven't specified what to return in case the if statement is false, it stills works and outputs 1. I thought maybe `foo(0)` just returned whatever `foo(1)` returned in the recursion, to check that I tried this:

```
int boo() {
    return 1;
}

int foo() {
    boo();
}
```

and called `foo()`, which resulted in a "foo must return a value" error, obviously changing `boo()` to `return boo()` fixed it. Sooo my question is why is the first case outputting root? And why is the second case even working?

Comment: Flowing off the end of a function returning something different than `void` without a `return` statement is undefined behavior. You got lucky there were no [nasal daemons](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nasal%20demons)!

Comment: @DietmarKühl thanks for the reference to nasal deamons :)

Comment: It seems strange to take and return a `node*&`... but you don't do anything with the results of the recursive calls to `search` (and thus don't have a valid `return`).

Comment: I think you're confused about how `return` works in a function. Every non-void function should `return` something. A nested function call's `return` value does not automatically become the parent's `return`. That is, execution proceeds in a function until an explicit `return` is encountered *within* the function itself (or the function ends).

Comment: As long as the function can reach the closing curly brace without executing a return statement, you can get any results. If you're getting the root pointer, then that's just an incidental effect. If you fix the function so that all paths execute a return statement, then the mysteries should go away.

Comment: Also, consider enabling warnings on your compiler. For gcc, the -Wall option will say something like "no return statement in function returning non-void".

Comment: @crashmstr, I returned a reference to the pointer so that I could reassign or delete it.

Comment: Thank you all very much, now I understand this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have here is that you do not propagate the return value of your recursive calls back to the original caller. As it is, when those calls return, the value is discarded.

Even worse, in cases where you don't find your match, you function as written fails to return anything, which is undefined behavior. The fact that you get the root node is more a quirk of the compiler or your current memory layout rather than a defined result.

As was pointed out by @Mike, for a binary tree, you should only be traversing one sub-tree in a search, based on whether or not your search value is greater or less than the value held by the current node. Traditionally, the left tree holds values smaller than the current node, while the right tree holds values that are greater.

Comment: Also they should not need to search both subtrees in a bst